# Postgres insert adds empty values as ' ' - how to show blank instead

Tags: postgresql, flask-wtforms, pgadmin

I'm assigning a value from a flask-WTForms form to insert into postgres.I'm using this code to assign value's to the fields

```
fabric_spool_number = form.fabric_spool_number.data
```

I'm then running a standard insert command to insert the data into a postgres table. However, when I view the table in pgAdmin, if a field was left blank, rather than showing an empty field, it shows a double apostrophe  instead i.e. '' .

EDIT:

This is the insert command:

```
def insert(form):
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO radio_archive_index_gui.radio_archive_index_gui_out (rai_number, carrier_format, physical_location, brand_title, recording_artist, producer, session, tx_date, network, programme_sub_category, programme_number, start_time_1, end_time_1, start_time_2, end_time_2, duration, part_number, number_of_parts, disc_number, number_of_discs, additional_info, notes, fabric_spool_number, username, edited_timestamp) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                (form.rai_number.data, form.carrier_format.data, form.physical_location.data, form.brand_title.data, form.recording_artist.data, form.producer.data, form.session.data, form.tx_date.data, form.network.data, form.programme_sub_category.data, form.programme_number.data, form.start_time_1.data, form.end_time_1.data, form.start_time_2.data, form.end_time_2.data, form.duration.data, form.part_number.data, form.number_of_parts.data, form.disc_number.data, form.number_of_discs.data, form.additional_info.data, form.notes.data, form.fabric_spool_number.data, form.username.data, dt))
        con.commit()
```

Here is the views form- just to say i've tried replacing the apostrophes in the request.args.get commands with blank spaces and None and this doesn't resolve the issue:

```
@app.route('/results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results():
        form=SendForm()
        ranumber = request.args.get('ranumber', '')
        rai_number = request.args.get('rai_number', '')
        brand_title = request.args.get('brand_title', "")
        carrier_format = request.args.get('carrier_format', '')
        recording_artist = request.args.get('recording_artist', '')
        producer = request.args.get('producer', '')
        session = request.args.get('session', '')
        tx_date = request.args.get('tx_date', '')
        network = request.args.get('network', '')
        programme_number = request.args.get('programme_number', '')
        start_time_1 = request.args.get('start_time_1', '')
        end_time_1 = request.args.get('end_time_1', '')
        start_time_2 = request.args.get('start_time_2', '')
        end_time_2 = request.args.get('end_time_2', '')
        duration = request.args.get('duration', '')
        part_number = request.args.get('part_number', '')
        number_of_parts = request.args.get('number_of_parts', '')
        disc_number = request.args.get('disc_number', '')
        number_of_discs = request.args.get('number_of_discs', '')
        additional_info = request.args.get('additional_info', '')
        notes = StringField = request.args.get('notes', '')
        fabric_spool_number = form.fabric_spool_number.data
        username = request.args.get('username', '')
        if request.method == 'POST':
                if form.validate_on_submit():
                        try:
                                models.insert(form)
                        except:
                                print ("hasn't worked")
                        else:
                                return redirect(url_for('success'))
                else:
                        number_of_discs = form.number_of_discs.data
                        number_of_parts = form.number_of_parts.data
                        disc_number = form.disc_number.data

        return render_template(
        'results.html', title='Results', ranumber=ranumber, rai_number=rai_number,brand_title=brand_title,carrier_format=carrier_format,recording_artist=recording_artist,producer=producer,session=session,tx_date=tx_date,network=network,programme_number=programme_number,start_time_1=start_time_1,end_time_1=end_time_1,start_time_2=start_time_2,end_time_2=end_time_2,duration=duration,part_number=part_number,number_of_parts=number_of_parts,disc_number=disc_number,number_of_discs=number_of_discs,additional_info=additional_info,notes=notes,fabric_spool_number=fabric_spool_number,username=username,form=form

)
```

Is this normal behavior? If not, what could be causing it?

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code. **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: edited, cheers.

Comment: What do you want? An empty string or null?

Comment: Null I guess. Is the apostrophe normal behavior?

Comment: I can not reproduce the apostrophe. Is it pgadmin4? Try it in psql. I guess the double apostrophe is just a representation of an empty string.

Comment: You're right, when I view it in terminal/psql they are empty fields. Thanks for your help.